# Internet connection from a pod inside an AKS cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I am trying to send an http request from my pod to the outside, but it seems impossible.
I currently have implemented a loadbalancer with fixed IP, but so far I just tested connections to the service.

Is there any specific constraint for it? Is it possible to overcome the issue?

Comment: can you show the code to see how you are doing it?

Comment: do you mean the call or how do I build the cluster? The only part that I believe could be relevant is how I do build the loadbalancer if you are interested.

Comment: It would be better if you could add both (call and load balancer build). Also, do check if the traffic from your cluster to outside is configured to allow or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your worker nodes where your pods live are probably in private subnets (it's good practice to keep them there) and if that is the case then it's not Kubernetes problem. You should setup NAT to allow outbound traffic. I'm not familiar with Azure, but you should also check other abstractions that control your traffic (like Security Group or NACLs in AWS)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could also be that I have to set the IP tables for the container itself for outbound traffic?

Comment: I don't think that would be the case. You can easily check that by running the container locally - if outbound connections are possible from you local machine running the container, then it's not a problem with the container itself. 99% of time it's infrastructure related stuff :)